# A vector in a linearly dependent indexed set is a linear combination of the PRECEDING vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, proof-explanation

A theorem in my LA book is characterized as follows:

An indexed set $S=\{\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_p}\}$ of two or more vectors is linearly dependent if and only if at least one vector is a linear combination of the others. **In fact, if S is linearly dependent and $\vec{v_1} \neq \vec{0}$, then some $\vec{v_j}$ (with $j > 1$) is a linear combination of the preceding vectors $\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_{j-1}}$.**

I don't get the boldface part at all. It seems oddly specific. Why does it have to be a linear combination of the **preceding** vectors? What if the vectors that $\vec{v_j}$ is a linear combination of are scattered around in the set, both preceding and succeeding $\vec{v_j}$?

Comment: Well, write out some dependence.  If $j$ is the greatest index that occurs with a non-zero coefficient, then $j$ works.

Comment: With just a little good will, the if $\vec v_1=\vec 0$, then also some $\vec v_j$, namely with $j=1$, is a linear combination of the preceding vectors.

Comment: @lulu yes, but again, why must it be the preceding vectors?

Comment: Since $j$ is maximal, by construction, everything else must be preceding.

Comment: @lulu but it's not... The theorem says nothing about the vector being maximal by construction, that's the proof, and the proof is beside the point here. I'm wondering why it has to precede the vector.

Comment: You've lost me.  I was giving a proof of the original claim.   I didn't look at the discussion past the statement of the claim...it seems too verbose.  Are you asking about the original claim or about some detail of a supposed proof?

Comment: Anyway, the reported proof is (not surprisingly) identical to mine.  They say "let $j$ be the largest subscript for which $c_j\neq 0$" which is exactly what I said.

Comment: Note;  there is no notion of a "maximal vector" here, either in my argument nor in the (more or less equivalent) argument provided.  In both cases, "maximal" refers to the index, not to the associated vector.

Comment: @lulu my apologies, perhaps I was unclear. I've edited out the part about the proof, as it's irrelevant. My question is concerned with why the vector has to be preceded by the vectors that constitute a linear combination. It seems arbitrary. Why can't the vectors that constitute the linear combination of $v_j$ not be scattered about in the set, both preceding and succeeding $v_j$?

Comment: Nobody said they couldn't!  The point is just that it is possible to do it the way they said, not that it is necessary.  If $\vec v_1+\vec v_2+\vec v_3=\vec 0$ then you can write $\vec v_3=-\vec v_1-\vec v_2$ to satisfy the claim, or you could write $\vec v_1=-\vec v_2-\vec v_3$ if you prefer ascending order, or you could write $\vec v_2=-\vec v_1-\vec v_3$ if you like that better.  Or (my preference) you could just leave it as $\vec v_1+\vec v_2+\vec v_3=\vec 0$.   There is no uniqueness here.

Comment: @lus, this theorem talks of **some vector** which is linear dep. in the preceding vectors in the set. You can also give a constructive proof: if $\;v_1=0\;$ then there's nothing to prove (read Hagen's comment above), otherwise: if $\;v_2\;$ is l.d. on $\;v_1\;$ we're done, otherwise $\;v_3\;$ ...and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this proposition:

> If a linear independent set of vectors $S$ is given, a vector $\vec v$ not in $S$ is given, such that $S\cup\{\vec v\}$ is linearly dependent, then $\vec v=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\vec u_i$ for a finite number of vectors $u_i\in S$.

You may prove this yourself. If you cannot, comment and I will include a proof.

To prove your boldface part, look at the sequence of sets:

$\{\vec{v_1}\},\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2}\},\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3}\},\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}\},\dots ,\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\dots,\vec{v_p}\}$

The first one is linearly independent. The next one may or may not be. If it is linearly dependent, you know that $\vec{v_2}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{v_1}$; otherwise, look at the next set to see if it is linearly dependent after adding one more vector. If $\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2}\}$ is linearly independent while $\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3}\}$ is not, you know that $\vec{v_3}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2}$, by applying the proposition in quote. If $\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3}\}$ is linearly independent, look at the next set $\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}\}$.

Repeat until you find the vector $\vec{v_j}$ which upon adding to the set $\{\vec{v_1},\dots,\vec{v_{j-1}}\}$ turns the linearly independent set into a linearly dependent set. You can always find one such $\vec{v_j}$, because your set $\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\dots,\vec{v_p}\}$ is assumed to be linearly dependent. Then you know $\vec {v_j}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{v_1},\dots,\vec{v_{j-1}}$, by applying the proposition in quote.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to know why the statement specifies $$ v_j = \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} c_k v_k $$

because actually it is possible that $$v_j = c_{j+1}v_{j+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{j-2} c_k v_k$$

The answer is because without loss of generality, we can solve for the biggest indexed vector, $v_{j+1}$: $$ v_{j+1} = \frac{1}{c_{j+1}}v_j - \sum_{k=1}^{j-2} \frac{1}{c_{j+1}}c_k v_k $$

And now we made index j+1 satisfy the theorem conditions